# Humanoid creatures with four “sticky” legs and eight eyes

Tags: creature-design, humanoid

These humanoid creatures need to walk on four legs. Pretty simple. Their legs also need to be sticky, like a gecko’s, so that they can walk on walls and upside down. They have eight eyes, two normal on the front of their heads, two normal on the back of their heads, two that can see infrared on the front of their heads, and two that can see infrared on the back of their heads. It can also move each pair separately. They are the size of the average human. What other physical effects will this have on them and what changes will have to be made to their anatomy?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t see a question here, just a description. Could you be more specific in what you’re asking?

Comment: Oh, sorry! I just noticed that! Thanks! I’m wondering what the physical effects would be and what changes will have to be made to their anatomy. Here, I’ll add it.

Comment: Four legs means they aren't humanoid.

Comment: Hello Lovie, welcome to world building SE. What exactly do you mean by physical effects and changes in their anatomy? Do you mean they change from human to these creatures? Or perhaps you want to know how they work in comparison to a normal human? Perhaps you just want to know if they can work at all? In either case we might need a little more details regarding what you need the most help with so that we can give you a good answer (and I'll tell you beforehand that something as big and heavy as a human might have a hard time using gecko physics to cling to walls and ceilings).

Comment: The question is unclear. Question "What anatomy changes do I need to make humans with four sticky legs and 8 eyes?" Answer "Take a human and change the anatomy to have two more legs and 6 more eyes." I don't know what else you're looking for.

Comment: These guys are definitely not humanoid lol

Answer (score 1):

### Legs

Your creature will probably have tiny bristles, arranged in ridges about 5 micometers wide, almost like fingerprints. You'd need to work out the math to estimate the holding power of these things.

[image]

### Eyes

You don't need 4 extra eyes to see infrared. All you need are an abundance of [rod structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_cell) in the retinas of the first four eyes. Of course, it's your world. Rods and cones can co-exist in the same retina.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the sticky gecko legs to work, the toes would have to be very long and wide in order to support the weight of a human sized animal. In addition to this, it would have to be relatively thin and have bones that are either hollow or very slim.

Answer (score 0):

In order to stick to walls, in a way that is useful for walking, they would need to be light. One way to achieve this would be to have a large, methane-filled bladder somewhere in their body, which would allow them to be floaty enough to stick to walls. This would probably entail a large torso, with skinny limbs as a way to further reduce weight